# How to convert/change mysql "->>" syntactic

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

In my project there is codegen function which produces this type of sql script:

```
ALTER TABLE `SomeTable` 
ADD COLUMN `column_country` JSON GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`col`->>'$[*].country') STORED NOT NULL
```

As result in database I have following table's DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `SomeTable`(
   `column_country` json GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
   (json_unquote(json_extract(`col`,'$[*].country'))) STORED NOT NULL,
)
```

Some how "->>" was converted to (json_unquote(json_extract(`...`,'...'))).
I need to wrap part "(json_unquote(json_extract(`col`,'$[*].country')))" to IFNULL function and to have as result:

```
CREATE TABLE `SomeTable`(
   `column_country` json GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
   (json_unquote(IFNULL(json_extract(`col`,'$[*].country', "[]")))) STORED NOT NULL,
)
```

But how can I do it with this "->>" syntactic ? At least where I can write about it?

Comment: *Some how "->>" was converted to (json_unquote(json_extract(...,'...'))).* `->>` is compact alias for `json_unquote(json_extract(` simply. *how can I do it with this "->>" syntactic ?* This is not possible. The table structure is stored in formalized/encoded binary form, the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is a reconstruction. This is similar to the difference for saved/stored JSON values where the ordering of object properties is changed/sorted.

Comment: JSON_UNQUOTE() doesn't do anything when you pass an array to it anyway.